# How to define a PowerShell function which requires elevation?

Tags: powershell, uac

Since I can't find any alternative to Linux' [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) elevation command, I have the following question:

How to define a PowerShell function which requires elevation? I mean UAC prompt.

Say, such function follows:

```
function system-check {
    SFC /ScanNow
}
```

**System:**

Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

**PowerShell:**

> ```
> Major  Minor  Build  Revision
> -----  -----  -----  --------
> 5      0      10586  117
> ```

**EDIT1:**

To be 100% understandable let me rephrase:

1. I run PowerShell as user
2. I run the aforementioned function `system-check`
3. I want the function to elevate in order to be able to execute the command; note, that I want the UAC prompt to appear

Comment: Note that many built in powershell commands and commands added by Microsoft modules (such as MSOL commands) often require elevation but in no way provide assistance in privilege elevation. They simply fail with cryptic error messages. If you build an elevation prompt into your scripts, you'll be providing more user friendliness than Microsoft themselves.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### To run a specific command from an elevated window:

```powershell
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList {$ScriptBlock} -verb RunAs
```

For example:

```powershell
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList {
    SFC /scannow
} -verb RunAs
```

#### To run a specific script from an elevated window:

```powershell
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -file MyScript.ps1' -verb RunAs
```

#### To run an entire PowerShell session prompting for UAC:

```powershell
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs
```

#### A function to return $True or $False if the current window is running with elevated permissions:

```powershell
function isadmin
 {
 #Returns true/false
   ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
 }
```

#### To ensure a script is only run As Admin, add this to the beginning:

```powershell
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
 {
  Echo "This script needs to be run As Admin"
  Break
 }
```

#### In PowerShell v4.0 the above can be simplified by using a #Requires statement:

```powershell
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

Source: [Run with elevated permissions](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-elevate.html)

Comment: The Security.Principal check is slightly more flexible than the straight #Requires directive, as you can do things like require admin privileges conditionally based on a parameter value.  For example, I only need admin access if I need to perform an IIS Reset, which I only need to do if I'm trying to rebuild my app (which is a parameter to the script), and so on.  So I'm glad both options were provided, here.